# Nginx Config: one Server name and two Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

Sorry, this question may have already being answered, but I can't find the answer that will help me.

My situation is like this.  We have a interal server, say called "helper.local.company"  We currently use it to run a Rails Application.  To get there a user just types "helper.local.company/ror_app1_route"

I would like to now install another app on to the server and then alloy the users to only type helper.local.company/ror_app2_route to get to the new app.

my current nginx conf file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen       80      default_server;
  server_name helper.local.company;

  root /var/www/apps/ror_app1/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rack_env production;
}
```

What would I need to change or add inorder to allow the two rails apps to work with out having to use sub-domains?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what keyword you need is 'passenger_base_uri'

reference from:http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri

The following is a simple example

Suppose that you already have a server virtual host entry:
    http {
    ...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.phusion.nl;
    root /websites/phusion;
    }
...

}
```

And you want your Ruby on Rails application to be accessible from the URL http://www.phusion.nl/rails.
To do this, make a symlink in the virtual host’s document root, and have it point to your Ruby on Rails application’s public folder. For example:

```
ln -s /webapps/mycook/public /websites/phusion/rails
```

Next, set passenger_enabled on and add a passenger_base_uri option to the server block:

```
http {
...

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.phusion.nl;
    root /websites/phusion;
    passenger_enabled on;        # <--- These lines have
    passenger_base_uri /rails;   # <--- been added.
    }
...
}
```

Then restart Nginx. The application has now been deployed.

You can deploy multiple Rails applications under a virtual host, by specifying passenger_base_uri multiple times. For example:

```
server {
...
passenger_base_uri /app1;
passenger_base_uri /app2;
passenger_base_uri /app3;
}
```